# Linear combination: Trying to calculate a weighted outcome

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a basic question: if you have a linear combination of two vectors u, v 
where u = $ \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \ \end{bmatrix} $ and v = $ \begin{bmatrix} w_1 \\ \vdots \\ w_n \ \end{bmatrix} $ and where $\ w_1+w_2+\cdots+w_n = 1 $ and $\ w_1, w_2, \ldots ,w_n $ are all positive real numbers and $\ a_1, a_2, \ldots ,a_n $ are all positive integers.

My question: Does $ u \cdot v $ converge to say a real number A no matter the size of $ n $?

Comment: If the vector space has finite dimension, *any* product $u\cdot v$  will  converge.

Comment: What do you mean by "converge" here? What is the sequence? $u\cdot v$ is just a real number by definition.

Comment: So really does there exist a limit A for u⋅v as n goes to infinity?